# Type of computer used for computation

Tags: matlab, simulation

In some scientific papers I see that authors provide what type of simulation tool and what type of computer was used for computation. For example:

> The computations were performed using MATLAB in double precision on a VAX 11/780 computer, the unit roundoff $u=2^{-56}\approx1.39\times10^{-17}$.

From my understanding Matlab has double precision by default and we can change it. And using the `round` function we can specify roundoff. But what should I specify in the type of computer part? Is this one correct: on a `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz` computer?

Comment: Yes, this seems like a reasonable description of what your computer is.

Comment: RAM is also important, both that you have enough of it that you don't use swap for the computation and that it's not some old, slow RAM chip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> From my understanding Matlab has double precision by default and we can change it.

Sort of. You can force it to run computations in single-precision, but you need to be very careful or your variables will be silently promoted to double precision. You can also use variable precision arithmetic (`vpa`, I think it's in the symbolic toolbox), but it is a lot slower and many functions do not work properly with it. A much better description is that Matlab is a tool built to work with `binary64` (double precision) floating point numbers, and using everything else would be a kludge.

> And using the `round` function we can specify roundoff.

Uhm, no, not at all. `round` rounds one single number to a specified number of decimal digits (approximately, because internally all numbers are represented in base-2). All arithmetic is still performed with the standard roundoff for double precision.

> But what should I specify in the type of computer part? Is this one correct: on a `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz` computer?

That sounds OK. You may want to specify also the Matlab version used. Many specify also the amount of RAM, but it is less clear if it serves a purpose or not in this context. If you are using Linux or Mac, you can get your processor's description with `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name` (note that there is one such line per virtual core, but they usually all coincide).